# discord.js import .json values into variable

Tags: arrays, variables, discord.js, var

I have these values stored in a .json as a very basic xp system (im aware of corruption issues, like to learn json before moving to db)

```
"267752827723492576":{"xp":308,"level":1}, "267752827723492576":{"xp":308,"level":1}
```

i want to import userid, xp, and level into a variable so i can make a leaderboard command, i already have working code for doing the comparison and sorting (below) . "user" being the variable containing my data from the json file

```
var users = {
    "":{"xp":0,"level":0},
    "":{"xp":0,"level":0},
    "":{"xp":0,"level":0},
    "":{"xp":0,"level":0},
    "":{"xp":0,"level":0},
      };

          let board = Object.entries(users)
                        .map(([key, val]) => ({id: key, ...val}))
                        .sort((a, b) => b.xp- a.xp);

          console.log(board);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Post is not clear, but you just wan't to import json?

`const users = require("path_to.json")`

You can also use `fs.readFile` alongside `JSON.parse`

Also instead of using an object to store the data you can use an array

with this format: (same format after you used your map method)

```
[{ id: "", xp: 200, level: 2}]
```

For preformance both have ups and downs, for actually getting a user by id an object is probably faster, but since you have to use `Object.entries` and `map` it probably evens out

Incase you do switch to array, here's how you would fetch a user

```js
// ... just stands for data here, not the deconstructing or rest syntax
const json = [{...}, {...}];
const user = json.find(f => f.id === "the-id-here");
```